# Can CSS automatically add text?

Tags: css

If you check the form at this link, you'll see that required fields have a `class="required"` in the CSS and a `*` in the markup.

http://drupal.org/user

Can the `*` which shows in the markup be added entirely with CSS for divs that have this class?

Comment: Removed `php` tag. No PHP here…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `after` pseudo class:

```
.required:after { content: "*"; }
```

or, because you explicitly asked for a div with that class:

```
div.required:after { content: "*"; }
```

Should work (for IE only since IE8)

---

You can apply any style to this, of course. You can even do things like this:

```
div.required:after:hover { /* Hello, I'm a geek. */ }
```

---

This can also be achieved with JavaScript. jQuery:

```
$(".required").append("*");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
span:after { content:"*"; }
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/W3gHU/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:after` or `before` css pseudo element for this, more info, also abt which browsers support it [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after).

Answer (score 1):

Try this page:

```
<html>

<style>
.required:after {
    color: red;
    content: "*"
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="required">Name</div> <input type="text">
<div class="required">Email</div> <input type="text">

</body>

</html>
```

:after is understood by probably everything except for IE (hopefully IE9 will have support)

**Update** taking into account comment of Šime Vidas:
it was just example of using. Of course it would bring more sense if we make it this way:

```
.required:before {
    color: red;
    content: "*"
}
....
<div>Name <input type="text" class="required"> </div>
```

then we can even add unobtrusive javascript validation to that field (so this way brings good advantages). The problem is that this refactored page will be displayed as we want it only in Opera (I checked it on all last builds of browsers, except for FireFox 4, but I'm not sure FF will change the way they take that style into account).
:after and :before do not work for input and img elements; [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field) related discussion of why. $(".required").before("*") from jQuery however will work everywhere, but that's more about JavaScript then CSS (and was mentioned before by other people).

Comment: It would make more sense if you'd put the INPUT elements inside the DIVs.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an image of a star via CSS. This should work in all browsers.

```
.required
{
background-image:url(/path/to/your/images/dir/required-field.png);
background-position:top right;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-right:10px;
}
```